# Prevent CSS Element From Expanding Page

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page that has three elements behind the main content (different z-indexes).  The problem is, when my page height is less than the end position of two of those elements (when I make my browser height smaller), they push underneath and past the bottom of the footer of the page, expanding the page height so a user can scroll past the footer and see the elements sticking through.  The elements causing the problem are backvisual2 and backvisual3.

I have tried overflow settings, but what I am looking for is overflow of only specific elements within the body to be ignored, not all of them.
What CSS will be necessary to hide the overflow of these three elements to prevent the page height from expanding beyond the footer?

**EDIT:** I added a minimum height to the body, and that has created a temporary fix in my example page linked above.

CSS:

```
#backvisual2
{
    height: 412px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("images/mapcover.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;

    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:169px;
    z-index:-2;
}
#backvisual3
{
    height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("images/backdropdivider.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:550px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.wrapper
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -220px;
}
html
{
    height: 100%;
}

body
{
    background-color: #EEE;
    height: 100%;
}
#footerstart
{
    background: transparent URL('images/footerdrop.png') repeat-x;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#footer
{
    margin-top: 64px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: #838383;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 850px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
    height: 132px;
}
#footersect
{
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 256px;
    border: 1px;
    padding-left: 16px;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <div id="backvisual1"></div>
    <div id="backvisual2"></div>
    <div id="backvisual3"></div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
            <div id=header></div>
                <div id=menu>
                ...
                </div>
            </div>
            [PAGE CONTENTS HERE]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footerstart"></div>
    <div id="footer">
    ...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a single line of code or selectors mentioned. Why do you want us to guess which elements have ``z-index`` and which do not? What do you mean by elements in the background? Please, provide more details and clarify the issue, not it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: All of them are visible at the link I provided.  Background would mean behind the main elements of the page, or "in the background."

Comment: @BitFracture Like what [@knitevision](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3317291/knitevision) has said, you should try to replicate your problem hosted on a common resource, like CodePen or JSFiddle. External link are prone to link rot and your example will be of little value to future users if you change your design, move your site, remove the page and etc.

Comment: @Terry I am not familiar with such services. I have added code to the initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have two offending `backvisual` divs on the page:

- `<div id="backvisual2"></div>` has a height of `412px`, which exceeds the viewport height when the viewport is sufficiently short.
- `<div id="backvisual1"></div>` has a top position of `550px` from the top, which causes it to be positioned outside the viewport when it happens.

What I can recommend is to use multiple background images (well supported in most browsers today). Alternatively, you should set your background image on the `.wrapper` or `.container` element instead of using it in an empty `<div>` with no semantic meaning.

p/s: Also, **replicate your issue in a fiddle in the future**. Linking to an external page will cause the question to lose relevance and context over time due to link rot.

Comment: The reason the last two (backvisual2 and backvisual3) are DIV elements is because the mapcover.jpg must be resized to fit its container, and no other element on the page has a container of those dimensions.  The following DIV has to go directly afterwards to create the transition edge, so it also must be a DIV.  I understand that backvisual2 could be integrated into the header, but also, it is causing no problems here.

Comment: "no other element on the page has a container of those dimensions" That, my friend, calls for rethinking how your site is laid out. It seems that your content is not wrapped in a container that has 100% viewport width, and you might want to look into your CSS and change that. Your solution of adding backgrounds into empty `<div>` is simply a stop-gap solution which, ironically, creates more problem than solving one.

Comment: If I contained everything, we would still be faced with exactly the same problem.  How to I make a "background-size:cover;" background within a set frame, and not create a DIV element that overflows the new container that will expand the page once again, creating the same problem?  This is not as simple as setting backgrounds.  This background needs to be within the frame I have it, and expand to fit to scale.  It may be possible for me to integrate #backvisual3 as a secondary background of that same element, however.